# How should I use the GitHub theme's code highlighting feature in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

I want to use default GitHub code highlighting on my blog, [like the code highlighting for Pre tags at https://tinyclouds.org/javascript_containers.](https://tinyclouds.org/javascript_containers)

My blog uses next.js 13 (app router) and mdx. I use next-mdx-remote/rsc to output the mdx.

I don't know how to implement exactly like GitHub code highlights.

[This is my repository](https://github.com/chebread/thisishaneum.com).